# Cómo imprimo lo que leo del teclado

Tags: python, python-2.x

Tengo el siguiente código con el que leo del teclado e imprimo por pantalla directamente:

```py
numero = input("Introduce un numero: ")
print "El numero que ingreso es: ", + $numero, "\n\n";
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto, no imprime nada:

```
Introduce un numero: 5
```

¿Cuál es el error en mi código?

Uso un IDE para Python 2.4

Comment: Cambia tu `print` por este:  `print ("El numero que ingreso es: ", numero)` y elimina de tu código esto: `>>>`

Comment: Hola @DanielMartinez, te damos la bienvenida al sitio. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre su funcionamiento general, y lee [ask] donde encontrarás recomendaciones para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que actualices la versión de Python, pues la que usas es muy antigua. Además `$numero` no es de Python, es de PHP. El `;` también sobra, en Python no es necesario aunque puedas ponerlo.

Tu código quedaría:

```
numero = input("Introduce un numero: ")
print("El numero que ingreso es: " + numero)
```

O también usando `format` que es lo recomendable para buenas prácticas:

```
numero = input("Introduce un numero: ")
print("El numero que ingreso es: {}".format(numero))
```

A partir de Python 3.7+ se puede utilizar [la expresión "f" o "F"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting):

```
numero = input("Introduce un numero: ")
print(f"El numero que ingreso es: {numero}")
```

Comment: en python 3.7+ `print(f"El numero que ingreso es: {numero}")`

Comment: No termino de comprender los negativos. Parece una respuesta sólida. Tras las ediciones, la pregunta se ve bien, pero me imagino que vinieron de gente que consideraba que la pregunta estaba mal y no debía responderse (por aquello de que no deberían responderse las preguntas que no se ajustan bien al formato del sitio).

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu error es el uso de $ y las "," para concatenar strings y numeros,

```py
>>> numero = input("Introduce un numero: ")
print "El numero que ingreso es: " + str(numero) + "\n\n"
```